# add submit to delete comment using ajax , php

Tags: ajax, jquery

Hi, I use a php code to view the all comments to any post from my sql and I want to add a submit button to every comment in order to delete it without refreshing the page, I mean using AJAX i don't know how to write that codes and connect it with html codes i want add  submit like this :

```
<form>
 <input type="submit" id="deletecomment"> 
 </form>
```

and connected it with AJAX and delete.php page to delete the comment (ajax,delete.php)???????

this is my codes

```
$result = mysql_query ("select * from post_comments WHERE link ='$getlink' order by link asc");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $id = $row['id'];
    $link = $row['link'];
    $time = $row['time'];
    $content = nl2br($row['content']);
    $name = ($row['link'] != '') ? '<h3 style="color:blue">'.$row['name'].'</h3>' : $row['name'];
    $imge = $row['imge'];

    echo '
        <div class="commentuserbackground">
            <img src="'.$imge.'" width="30px" height="30px">
            <div id="comment-'.$id.'" class="username1">'.$name.'</div>
            <div class="username2">'.$content.'</div><div class="commenttime"><h4 style="color:#5a5a5a">'.$time.'</h4>
        </div></div>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the jquery lib included in your html, you could do something like this:

```
# html page
<button data-id="1" class="delete_comment" /> # no need to wrap in form

# At the bottom of the body tag
$(".delete_comment").click(function(e){ 
  e.preventDefault();
  var $button = $(this), $comment = $button.parent(), id = $button.data("id");
  $.ajax({
    type: 'DELETE',
    url: "/path/to/comment/" + id,
    success: function(){ $comment.remove(); }
  });
});
```

Comment: ok Emil i will put your html codes in side echo to print with every comment . ok i use jquery lib in my html but what do u mean in line 6 ("url:path/to/comment/"+id) what about id because every comments has its id